# Parsing a nested array of objects with Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I want to parse a JSON object and create a JSONEvent with the given `name` and `args`

I'm using Aeson, and right now I'm stucked on converting `"args":[{"a": "b"}]` to a `[(String, String)]`.

Thank's in advance!

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import Data.Aeson

data JSONEvent = JSONEvent [(String, String)] (Maybe String) deriving Show

instance FromJSON JSONEvent where
  parseJSON j = do
    o <- parseJSON j
    name <- o .:? "name"
    args <- o .:? "args" .!= []
    return $ JSONEvent args name

let decodedEvent = decode "{\"name\":\"edwald\",\"args\":[{\"a\": \"b\"}]}" :: Maybe JSONEvent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a bit more elaborate example based on ehird's example. Note that the explicit typing on calls to parseJSON is unnecessary but I find them useful for documentation and debugging purposes. Also I'm not sure what you intended, but with `args` with multiple values I simply concatenate all the `args` together like so:

```
*Main> decodedEvent2
Just (JSONEvent [("a","b"),("c","d")] (Just "edwald"))
*Main> decodedEvent3
Just (JSONEvent [("a","b"),("c","d")] (Just "edwald"))
```

Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as HM
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Aeson

import qualified Data.Attoparsec as P
import Data.Aeson.Types (Parser)
import qualified Data.Aeson.Types as DAT
import qualified Data.String as S

data JSONEvent = JSONEvent [(String, String)] (Maybe String) deriving Show

instance FromJSON JSONEvent where
  parseJSON = parseJSONEvent

decodedEvent = decode "{\"name\":\"edwald\",\"args\":[{\"a\": \"b\"}]}" :: Maybe JSONEvent
decodedEvent2 = decode "{\"name\":\"edwald\",\"args\":[{\"a\": \"b\"}, {\"c\": \"d\"}]}" :: Maybe JSONEvent
decodedEvent3 = decode "{\"name\":\"edwald\",\"args\":[{\"a\": \"b\", \"c\": \"d\"}]}" :: Maybe JSONEvent

emptyAesonArray :: Value
emptyAesonArray = Array $ V.fromList []

parseJSONEvent :: Value -> Parser JSONEvent
parseJSONEvent v =
  case v of
    Object o -> do
      name <- o .:? "name"
      argsJSON <- o .:? "args" .!= emptyAesonArray
      case argsJSON of
        Array m -> do
          parsedList <- V.toList <$> V.mapM (parseJSON :: Value -> Parser (HM.HashMap T.Text Value)) m
          let parsedCatList = concatMap HM.toList parsedList
          args <- mapM (\(key, value) -> (,) <$> (return (T.unpack key)) <*> (parseJSON :: Value -> Parser String) value) parsedCatList
          return $ JSONEvent args name
        _ -> fail ((show argsJSON) ++ " is not an Array.")
    _ -> fail ((show v) ++ " is not an Object.")

-- Useful for debugging aeson parsers
decodeWith :: (Value -> Parser b) -> String -> Either String b
decodeWith p s = do
  value <- P.eitherResult $ (P.parse json . S.fromString) s
  DAT.parseEither p value
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an aeson expert, but if you have `Object o`, then *o* is simply a `HashMap Text Value`; you could use [Data.HashMap.Lazy.toList](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unordered-containers/latest/doc/html/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html#v%3atoList) to convert it into `[(Text, Value)]`, and [Data.Text.unpack](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text.html#v%3aunpack) to convert the `Text`s into `String`s.

So, presumably you could write:

```
import Control.Arrow
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Foldable as F
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as HM
import Data.Aeson

instance FromJSON JSONEvent where
  parseJSON j = do
    o <- parseJSON j
    name <- o .:? "name"
    Object m <- o .:? "args" .!= []
    args <- map (first T.unpack) . HM.toList <$> F.mapM parseJSON m
    return $ JSONEvent args name
```

Comment: I don' really get what's going on. I'm quite new at Haskell.. This is what I get:

Comment: @masylum: Ah, I misread your code slightly. Do you want the parsing to fail if, e.g. you have `"args": [{"a":"b","c":d"}]`, i.e. an object with more than one key in the list? As for the "not in scope" error, you forgot the `import Control.Arrow`.